# Get GeoLocation using phonegap when Location services disabled in iPad

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I am developing iPad application using phonegap (cordova 1.9.0). I need to get current position of the user. 
I used following code and it works fine when Location services are enabled.

```
function onDeviceReady() {  
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);   
 }

function onSuccess(position) {
 console.log(position.coords.latitude + "-" + position.coords.longitude);
}

  function onError(error) {   
     alert('code: '    + error.code           
      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');  
  }
```

My problem is that this code not working when Location services are disabled. I need to get current location if Location service are enabled or disabled.

Anyone tell me how to get current location in this situtation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the current location when location services are disabled. That would be a violation of a user's privacy. The point of disabling location services on a device is to prevent applications from getting the current location.

What I've done is display my own dialog with a lengthy explanation of why I need location services before calling `getCurrentPosition()`. I explain that the app won't work without it. I also say something like:

> Your device may also ask you for permission.

This increases the chances of someone saying yes to the iPhone dialog.

Comment: So how can i do my requement?

Comment: You can't. The best you can do is tell the user that location services are required to run the application.